# Pandas -> GroupBy two columns adding size as third

Tags: python, pandas

What is the equivalent in pandas for the SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT key1,key2,count(1) FROM mytable GROUP BY key1,key2
```

Please notice: i can still access `key1` and `key2` independently as i iterate line-by-line... I couldn't manage to it via

```py
myDataFrame.groupBy(by=['key1','key2']).size()
```

The above code prints the keys and the count of occurrences but i can't access the keys individually

How does that query translates to pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `reset_index()`

```
myDataFrame.groupBy(by=['key1','key2']).size().reset_index()
```

Comment: worked! nice! quick question... how do i fetch the new third column? i can do groups.iloc[0].key1 and key2, but not the third one...